How to parameterize a dataset so I can use multiple excel files in a blob folder to pass to PowerQuery one by one?
I am in Data factory and I need help to parameterize a dataset so I can use multiple files in a blob folder to process in PowerQuery and then send to an AzureSQL table for sink(storage). I do not want to make 100 datasets if I want to process the 100 excel files in the same way using PowerQuery.
I have successfully executed a pipeline as follows:
Get Metadata activity to read all files in a blob folder (.xlsx), then use a for each loop to get each file and inside that an activity to copy it to an Azure SQL DB.
Now I want to see if I can do following or similar:
Get a list of files in a blob folder or get full blob addresses of files, and then use a for loop to try to pass one file/file address (per loop turn) and process it through PowerQuery.
Is this even possible right now? Really stuck with this. I want to process data in PowerQuery before loading it to a sink basically.
Alternative ideas encouraged!

You can pass dynamically the filename in power query dataset also. Below are the detailed steps.

Take the Get metadata activity and get the list of file names from that activity.



Then take the for-each activity and give thegetmetadata activity output array to for-each activity



Inside for-each activity, add the power query there. Open the power query source dataset and give the dynamic content expression for the dataset filename as @item().name.



Give the sink name in the sink settings of power query activity.

This way, you can achieve the requirement of using the same power query pipeline for all files.

Thanks @Aswin, so I tried following that: Did the metadata activity (Child Items) and added the @activity('Get Metadata').output.value to the for loop. For the next step: Do you suggest that I make the dataset first and if yes, should I point the dataset to a particular .xlsx file or just the directory path? It also might need sheet name/index?
Also, can you show how you made your PowerQuery since it only succeeds initially if we are pointing to a single file, not directory? Did you manage to successfully run this pipeline and pass data from multiple files to process in PowerQuery in loop?


When child items is added in get metadata activity, you can give the expression as @activity('get Metadata').output.childItems in foreach activity.
Yes, Create dataset and give the directory path. In file name, give the expression as @item().name.
I used delimited text dataset. If you are using .xls data, then you need to give sheet name/ index also.
Yes, data is processed from multiple files in loop.


Thanks, I added @activity('get Metadata').output.childItems in foreach, next did the @item().name as filename along with a sheet index, I was able to validate the pipeline without errors. The only thing is when I go to check PowerQuery I cannot see it resolving to anything because the file name is item.name(). Here: [img]https://i.imgur.com/aKCl2jR.png[/img]
I would like to see what is happening in PowerQuery to add more steps in there.

initially, you can give the file name and then define the power query. Later replace the file name with @item().name.

Will the @item().name in filename give error every time in a few days after I publish the dataset, it gets yellow with a warning. Also the sheet name keeps giving a Failed red warning every now and then.

Ignore the warning. Can u share the screen shot of failed red warning

I cannot seem to ignore the warning, since that is making my PowerQuery fail every other morning after publishing the changes to the dataset. I had to give up doing it the PowerQuery way as it was too slow compared to normal dataflows in ADF.

Okay. Based on your requirement, mapping dataflow is better.
